# Select four points in a plane to make a parallelogram

Tags: geometry

I want to select four points in a plane make a parallelogram. Tried

```
L = {x, y, z} /. 
   Solve[{2 x + 2 y +  z - 5 == 0, -7 <= x <= 7, -7 <= y <= 7, -7 <= 
      z <= 7, x y z != 0, (x - y) (y - z) (z - x) != 0}, {x, y, z}, 
    Integers];
Length[L]
ss = Subsets[L, {4}];
t = Select[
  ss, (12 == Length[Union[#[[1]], #[[2]], #[[3]], #[[4]]]] ) && 
    Norm[Cross[#[[2]] - #[[1]], #[[3]] - #[[1]]]] !=  
     0 && #[[2]] - #[[1]] == #[[4]] - #[[3]] &]
Length[t]
```

I got

> ```
> {{{-7, 7, 5}, {-3, 6, -1}, {-2, 4, 1}, {2, 3, -5}}, 
>  {{-7, 7, 5}, {-2, 6, -3}, {-1, 2, 3}, {4, 1, -5}}, 
>  {{-6, 7, 3}, {-3, 5, 1}, {-1, 6, -5}, {2, 4, -7}}, 
>  {{-5, 4, 7}, {-2, 6, -3}, {2, -1, 3}, {5, 1, -7}}, 
>  {{-5, 6, 3}, {-2, 1, 7}, {2, 4, -7}, {5, -1, -3}}, 
>  {{-4, 7, -1}, {-2, 6, -3}, {3, 2, -5}, {5, 1, -7}}, 
>  {{-3, 3, 5}, {1, -2, 7}, {2, 4, -7}, {6, -1, -5}}, 
>  {{-2, 1, 7}, {-1, 6, -5}, {3, -3, 5}, {4, 2, -7}}, 
>  {{-1, 2, 3}, {1, 5, -7}, {4, -5, 7}, {6, -2, -3}}, 
>  {{-1, 5, -3}, {1, -2, 7}, {4, 2, -7}, {6, -5, 3}}, 
>  {{1, 4, -5}, {2, -1, 3}, {6, -2, -3}, {7, -7, 5}}, 
>  {{1, 5, -7}, {2, 3, -5}, {6, -2, -3}, {7, -4, -1}}, 
>  {{3, 2, -5}, {4, -2,1}, {6, -3, -1}, {7, -7, 5}}, 
>  {{4, 2, -7}, {5, -3, 1}, {6, -1, -5}, {7, -6, 3}}}
> ```

The order (from left to right) of the four points

> ```
> {{-3, 3, 5}, {1, -2, 7}, {2, 4, -7}, {6, -1, -5}}
> ```

doesn't make a parallelogram.

How can I arrange the order of vertices from left to right to always get a parallelogram.

Comment: `FindCurvePath`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to interchange the 3rd and 4th points.

```
data =
  {{{-7, 7, 5}, {-3, 6, -1}, {-2, 4, 1}, {2, 3, -5}}, 
   {{-7, 7, 5}, {-2, 6, -3}, {-1, 2, 3}, {4, 1, -5}}, 
   {{-6, 7, 3}, {-3, 5, 1}, {-1, 6, -5}, {2, 4, -7}}, 
   {{-5, 4, 7}, {-2, 6, -3}, {2, -1, 3}, {5, 1, -7}}, 
   {{-5, 6, 3}, {-2, 1, 7}, {2, 4, -7}, {5, -1, -3}}, 
   {{-4, 7, -1}, {-2, 6, -3}, {3, 2, -5}, {5, 1, -7}}, 
   {{-3, 3, 5}, {1, -2, 7}, {2, 4, -7}, {6, -1, -5}}, 
   {{-2, 1, 7}, {-1, 6, -5}, {3, -3, 5}, {4, 2, -7}}, 
   {{-1, 2, 3}, {1, 5, -7}, {4, -5, 7}, {6, -2, -3}}, 
   {{-1, 5, -3}, {1, -2, 7}, {4, 2, -7}, {6, -5, 3}}, 
   {{1, 4, -5}, {2, -1, 3}, {6, -2, -3}, {7, -7, 5}}, 
   {{1, 5, -7}, {2, 3, -5}, {6, -2, -3}, {7, -4, -1}}, 
   {{3, 2, -5}, {4, -2,1}, {6, -3, -1}, {7, -7, 5}}, 
   {{4, 2, -7}, {5, -3, 1}, {6, -1, -5}, {7, -6, 3}}};

twiddle[{a_, b_, c_, d_}] := {a, b, d, c}

 parallelograms = twiddle /@ data
```

> ```
> {{{-7, 7, 5}, {-3, 6, -1}, {2, 3, -5}, {-2, 4, 1}},
>  {{-7, 7, 5}, {-2, 6, -3}, {4, 1, -5}, {-1, 2, 3}},
>  {{-6, 7, 3}, {-3, 5, 1}, {2, 4, -7}, {-1, 6, -5}},
>  {{-5, 4, 7}, {-2, 6, -3}, {5, 1, -7}, {2, -1, 3}},
>  {{-5, 6, 3}, {-2, 1, 7}, {5, -1, -3}, {2, 4, -7}},
>  {{-4, 7, -1}, {-2, 6, -3}, {5, 1, -7}, {3, 2, -5}},
>  {{-3, 3, 5}, {1, -2, 7}, {6, -1, -5}, {2, 4, -7}},
>  {{-2, 1, 7}, {-1, 6, -5}, {4, 2, -7}, {3, -3, 5}},
>  {{-1, 2, 3}, {1, 5, -7}, {6, -2, -3}, {4, -5, 7}},
>  {{-1, 5, -3}, {1, -2, 7}, {6, -5, 3}, {4, 2, -7}},
>  {{1, 4, -5}, {2, -1, 3}, {7, -7, 5}, {6, -2, -3}},
>  {{1, 5, -7}, {2, 3, -5}, {7, -4, -1}, {6, -2, -3}},
>  {{3, 2, -5}, {4, -2, 1}, {7, -7, 5}, {6, -3, -1}},
>  {{4, 2, -7}, {5, -3, 1}, {7, -6, 3}, {6, -1, -5}}}
> ```

```
Multicolumn[
  Graphics3D[{Hue[RandomReal[]], Polygon[#]}, 
    Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral"] & /@ parallelograms,
  2]
```

[image: grid]

Comment: Where is wrong in my code?

Comment: Nothing, so far as I can tell. Your points are getting sorted by some operation along the line, so you just have to reorder them at end.

Comment: @toandhsp The points come out `Sort`-ed from `Subsets`, I believe.  But I wonder if a different `twiddle` might be needed in some case. (I wouldn't be surprised if `twiddle` always works. It should work generically, and it works in all the edge-cases I can imagine. But can I imagine them all? I don't have time to sort it out, right now.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you very much. I want a general code in every cases.

Answer (score 0):

**strong text**

```
For[a = 3, a < 8, a++, 
 L = {x, y, z} /. 
   Solve[{2 x + 2 y + z - 5 == 0, -a <= x <= a, -a <= y <= a, -a <= 
      z <= a, x y z != 0, (x - y) (y - z) (z - x) != 0}, {x, `enter code here`y, z}, 
    Integers];
 ss = Subsets[L, {4}];
 t = Select[ss,
   (Norm[#[[1]] - #[[2]]] == Norm[#[[3]] - #[[4]]] && 
       Norm[#[[1]] - #[[4]]] == Norm[#[[2]] - #[[3]]]) \[Or]
     (Norm[#[[1]] - #[[2]]] == Norm[#[[3]] - #[[4]]] && 
       Norm[#[[1]] - #[[3]]] == Norm[#[[2]] - #[[4]]]) \[Or]
     (Norm[#[[1]] - #[[3]]] == Norm[#[[2]] - #[[4]]] && 
       Norm[#[[1]] - #[[4]]] == Norm[#[[2]] - #[[3]]])
    &];
 Print["(", Length[L], ", " , Length[t], ")"]`enter code here`]
```

Comment: You might want to check your formatting. Some stray clicks have created errors in your code.